# Do the different spoilers on an A321 extend by different amounts?

Tags: airbus-a320, control-surfaces, spoilers

I recently flew with an A321 and watched the left wing while the pilot tested the control surfaces before lift off. I noticed that one of the spoilers angled upwards much less than all others. In the drawing below, it was spoiler number 3 (labelled as an "air brake" *[sic]*). The pilot extended them twice, and the behaviour was the same each time.

[image: schematic drawing of left wing of an A318/A319/A320 showing the naming of different control surfaces]

Comment: Questions are closed as duplicate when it's the same question: "do" is very different from "why", and the answers are very different. I voted to reopen.

Comment: The answer for "do they do X" is certainly provided when the answer to "why do they do X" confirms that X happens as introduction to explaining why. I see no value in reopening, particularly since the OP found the duplicate thread to be useful.

Comment: @RalphJ: To avoid a discussion here, now on meta: [Why is this A321 spoilers question closed as a duplicate?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4300/14897)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [image]
> A321's flight controls check via [YouTube](https://youtu.be/4MgDTAI62dg?t=245)

They indeed do on the A321. To be precise, what you saw happens during the roll function (banking left/right), not the slowing down and spoiling lift functions. Here's an extract from the A321's flight manual:

> ROLL CONTROL
>
> [...]
>
> The maximum deflection of the spoilers is:
>
> - 35 ° for spoilers 2, 4, and 5
> - **7 ° for spoilers 3.**

And compare with the A320:

> ROLL CONTROL
>
> [...]
>
> The maximum deflection of the spoilers is 35 °.

For the difference: [Why is there a difference in the max spoilers extension between the A320 and A321 in a roll?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/84089/14897)

*Note: both do not use spoiler 1 for rolling.*

---

Further reading:

- [Why do outboard spoilers deploy more than the inboard spoiler on the A320?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/47945/14897)
- [Why is deploying speed brakes not recommended with the flaps extended?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/47879/14897)